# What if there is a process named as self-branch code review in the Git flow?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I always look forward to a process within Git flow, where reviwers can have code review in a certain branch by selecting specific commits, also like giving comments in certain commits. However, comments are always not keepable when commits are covered, and it is also hard to trace back the discussion history. If there is a self-branch review, such a review can be not forced, but willing, which means that developers do not have to checkout a branch to give out a MR or PR, where reviewer can only review code right now. Any idea?

Comment: Gerrit provides excellent features for code review. See https://www.gerritcodereview.com/. It's a hosting service like github and gitlab. But to use and maintain it may be a big burden. If you want to use Git only, `git notes` may help.

Comment: we have deeply depend on Gitlab, and I hope there is a integration tool. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your questions is unclear to me. What do you mean by comments are not keepable? Obviously, your comments will not just get randomly deleted. What is a "self-branch review"? Why do you think you can not force a review? This is implemented via the Merge Approvals feature. Try formatting your explanations into paragraphs and ask a precise question at the end.